# Retrieving data from multiple span under main span class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following html code:

```
<span class="double-line-ellipsis">
 <span>
  ₹ 2800 for 2 (approx)
 </span>
 <span>
  |
 </span>
 <a data-w-onclick="stopClickPropagation|w1-restarant" href="/Bangalore-restaurants/cantonese-cuisine">
  Cantonese
 </a>
 <span>
  ,
 </span>
 <a data-w-onclick="stopClickPropagation|w1-restarant" href="/Bangalore-restaurants/chinese-cuisine">
  Chinese
 </a>
</span>
```

So My requirement is I need ₹ 2800 for 2 (approx) retrieved separately and Cantonese, Chinese retrieved separately.

But when I am using below code:

```
det = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'double-line-ellipsis'})
        print(det.text)
```

I am getting everything together like "₹ 2800 for 2 (approx) | Cantonese, Chinese" which is making it difficult for me to copy the info into excel in different columns like price and cuisine.

I am new to this, can someone please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
price = soup.select_one('span[class="double-line-ellipsis"] span').text.strip()
langs = soup.select('a[data-w-onclick="stopClickPropagation|w1-restarant"]')
print(price)
for lang in langs:
    print(lang.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
₹ 2800 for 2 (approx)
Cantonese
Chinese
```